# react-native-draggable-flatlist not working inside ScrollView

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-draggable-flatlist

I am struggling for last couple of months to achieve a requirement where I'm having a draggable flatlist and a flatlist in a single scrollview and I should able to scroll the whole content.

The draggable flatlist should have autoscroll as well, that means when the list is too long and I'm trying to drag it out of the viewport, the list should scroll automatically unless I drop it.

I know the requirement is pretty much tricky but I am not getting any clue to make it work completely.

I am using the below code and I am using 'react-native-draggable-flatlist'(https://github.com/computerjazz/react-native-draggable-flatlist) for this purpose.

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import DraggableFlatList from 'react-native-draggable-flatlist'
import { Component } from 'react'

const exampleData = [...Array(20)].map((d, index) => ({
  key: `item-${index}`, // For example only -- don't use index as your key!
  label: index,
  backgroundColor: `rgb(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)}, ${index *
  5}, ${132})`
}));

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: exampleData,
    scrollEnabled: true
  };
  onEnableScroll = (value: boolean) => {
    this.setState({
      enableScrollViewScroll: value,
    });
  };

  renderItem = ({ item, index, drag, isActive }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          height: 100,
          backgroundColor: isActive ? "blue" : item.backgroundColor,
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center"
        }}
        onLongPress={drag}
      >
        <Text
          style={{
            fontWeight: "bold",
            color: "white",
            fontSize: 32
          }}
        >
          {item.label}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView
        style={{ backgroundColor: '#000', flex: 1 }}
        contentContainerStyle={{ paddingTop: 800, paddingBottom: 100 }}
        scrollEnabled={this.state.scrollEnabled}
      >
        <DraggableFlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => `draggable-item-${item.key}`}
          onMoveBegin={() => this.setState({ scrollEnabled: false })}
          onMoveEnd={({ data }) => {
            this.setState({ scrollEnabled: true, data });
          }}
        />

        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => `draggable-item-${item.key}`}
        />

      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.lighter,
  },
  engine: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
  },
  body: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  },
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: Colors.black,
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: Colors.dark,
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
  footer: {
    color: Colors.dark,
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: '600',
    padding: 4,
    paddingRight: 12,
    textAlign: 'right',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: have you found any solutions yet? im facing this issue

Comment: @QuangThái - Not yet

Answer (score 2):

You should use `ListFooterComponent` and `ListHeaderComponent` method to render items.

Please change your render method like below code.

```
render() {
      return (
        <View
          style={{ backgroundColor: '#000', flex: 1 }}
        >
          <DraggableFlatList
            data={this.state.data}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => `draggable-item-${item.key}`}
            onMoveBegin={() => this.setState({ scrollEnabled: false })}
            onMoveEnd={({ data }) => {
              this.setState({ scrollEnabled: true, data });
            }}
            ListFooterComponent={() => {
              return <View>
                <FlatList
                  data={this.state.data}
                  renderItem={this.renderItem}
                  keyExtractor={(item, index) => `draggable-item-${item.key}`}
                />
              </View>
            }}
          />
        </View>
      );
}
```

Comment: Spot on! This solved the issue for me...

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I have another `ScrollView` composition.
My solution was found in this repository:

##### [React Native Draggable FlatList](https://github.com/computerjazz/react-native-draggable-flatlist)

I replaced:

1. `ScrollView -> NestableScrollContainer`
2. `DraggableFlatList  -> NestableDraggableFlatList`

Initially there was one `DraggableFlatList` but in this case I was able to scroll via the `DraggableFlatList`